# How do I generate all n-sized sets from a list of k items?

Tags: python

Given a set of `k` items, (e.g., `{1,2,3}`, for `k=3`), how do I generate all possible sets of length `n` using the original set's values? There should be `k**n` such lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `itertools` module:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> s = set((1,2,3))
>>> list(permutations(s))

[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]

>>> list(permutations(s, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

***UPDATE:***
Maybe this is more like what was asked for:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, combinations_with_replacement, permutations
>>> list(set(chain.from_iterable(permutations(x) for x in combinations_with_replacement(s, 3))))
[(1, 3, 2),
 (1, 3, 1),
 (3, 3, 1),
 (1, 1, 1),
 (3, 3, 3),
 (2, 3, 2),
 (3, 3, 2),
 (2, 3, 3),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (3, 2, 2),
 (3, 1, 3),
 (3, 2, 3),
 (3, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (3, 1, 1),
 (3, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 3),
 (2, 1, 3),
 (2, 2, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 1),
 (1, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: I had a similar interpretation of the question. But `list(permutations(s, 3))` returns `6` lists but @OP needs to return `k^n` lists `(27)`.